# G++: error: unrecognized option ‘-soname’

Tags: g++

I am trying to build SLitrani on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I have already built ROOT 5.34.03 from source and I did figure out how to set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH variables for $ROOTDEV so the problem is not there but when I try to make SplineFit I get

```
>>> g++: error: unrecognized option ‘-soname=libSplineFit.so’
make: *** [libSplineFit.so] Error 1
```

I also did change all the `-m32` to `-m64` in the Makefiles so I don't know what is going on. I was able to get TwoPad installed but I can't continue from SplineFit. I have been on this build for quite some time and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

From memory, `soname` is a linker operation, not a compiler one. So, if you're doing it with `g++`, you may need to change the option into something like:

```
-Wl,-soname=libSplineFit.so
```

The following transcript shows that this is necessary:

```
pax> g++ --soname=x -Wall -o qq qq.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-fsoname=x"

pax> g++ -Wl,-soname=x -Wall -o qq qq.cpp

pax>
```

From the [online GNU docs for gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link%20Options):

> **-Wl,option:** pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas.

Comment: That worked!  But sadly only for the creation of the library, now I have a multitude of 'undefined references' to resolve.

Comment: @user1850483, that would be reason to ask even _more_ questions here on SO :-)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but after a week of struggling I thought I should post my findings.

I've successfully edited the makefiles for this so they can compile on Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

You can remove the -soname option completely, it seemingly is unnecessary.

As mentioned: all "m32" change to "m64".

You can replace "$ROOTSYS/libs" with "$ROOTLIBS"

and with TwoPad makefile reorder the library order (under LIBS += (.....)) so that -lTwoPad is NOT last on the list, and for VisuSLitrani make -lPhysMore last in its group.

As far as I know the errors saying "set but not used" can be ignored.

If any of this still doesn't work contact me back and I can send you my makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://man7.org/conf/lca2006/shared_libraries/slide4b.html) a nice explanation of the -soname linker option, how to call it and what it is good for.

**Summary**

You can simply use `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo_v1.so -o libfoo_v1.so libfoo_v1.o` and skip the following discussion ;)

- call it as `gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo_v1.so libfoo_v1.o`
- after compiling you need to create an symbolic link pointing to libfoo_v1.so `ln -s libfoo_v1.so libfoo.so` before you can execute your code.
- This is used to link against different shared libraries during compiletime and runtime. Obviously these libraries need a similar interface. You can use this for managing different versions.